# When I run manage.py dbshell it return an error saying too many options

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite

This is the error I get why run python manage.py dbshell from my django project while using sqlite with database named db.sqlite3:

```
sqlite3: Error: too many options: "3"
```

I can run other commands such as syncdb, but I can't get into dbshell. Any idea?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/lqHdb7g2G0Q

Comment: Thanks. I already read those links, but I didn't try one of the solutions since I thought messing with db.backends.sqlite3\client.py was a bad idea. I went ahead and included extra quotes before and after  `def runshell(self):
        args = [self.executable_name,
                '"' + self.connection.settings_dict['NAME'] + '"']`

That did the job! http://stackoverflow.com/a/8721156/870943